# 依存ライブラリのバージョンを制限したくないが、開発時は特定のバージョンを利用したい。どうすればよいか？

Tags: python, poetry

## 環境

- Python 3.11.2
- poetry 1.7.1

## 背景

Python3.8から3.11をサポートするツールを開発しています。
ツールはpandasを利用しています。
依存解決にはpoetryを利用しています。

Python3.11で以下の`pyproject.toml`を利用して`poetry install`コマンドを実行すると、pandas 2.0.3がインストールされました。
pandas 2.1以降はPython3.8をサポートしていないので、Python3.8をサポートする最新バージョンであるpandas 2.0.3がインストールされました。

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "test"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["Your Name <you@example.com>"]
readme = "README.md"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.8"
pandas = "*"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

## やりたいこと

ツールの開発環境はPython 3.11です。
ツールを開発する際は、最新のpandasバージョンである2.2.0を利用したいです。
[pandasのCopy-on-Write](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/copy_on_write.html)に対応するため、以下の設定で警告を出すようにしたいからです。

```
pd.options.mode.copy_on_write = "warn"
```

pandas 2.0.3では上記の設定ができないので、pandas 2.2.0で開発したいです。

## 質問

開発時にpandas 2.2.0をインストールするには、どのようにすればよいでしょうか？

## 検討したこと

以下のようなpyproject.tomlで、pythonバージョンによってpandasのバージョンを切り替えれば、開発環境でpandas 2.2.0をインストールできます。

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.8"
pandas = [
  {version = ">=2.1", python = ">=3.9"},
  {version = "<2.1", python = "=3.8"}
]
```

しかし、このpyproject.tomlを利用すると、このツール利用者（pip installでツールをインストールするユーザー）のpandasを制限することになります。
ツールではpandasの特定バージョンでしか動かないようなコードはないので、pandasのどのバージョンでもツールを利用できるようにしたいです。
したがって、上記のpyproject.tomlは採用できないと考えています。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

グループを指定してはどうでしょう

- `poetry add [パッケージ名] --group [グループ名]`
- `poetry install --only [グループ名]`

`group dev` (開発環境？)なら, `pyproject.toml` は以下のような項目へ

```
[tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies]
```

Comment: 解決しました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: pyproject.tomlに同じパッケージを記載してはいけないと思っていましたが、グループが異なれば問題ないんですね。知りませんでした。

Answer (score 0):

@oriri さんの回答に従い、poetryのグループにもpandasを指定すれば、解決しました。

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "install-test-312"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["yuji38kwmt"]
readme = "README.md"
packages = [{include = "install_test_312"}]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.8"
pandas = "*"

[tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies]
pandas = {version = ">=2.1", python = ">=3.9"}

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

```
$ poetry show
numpy           1.26.3 Fundamental package for array computing in Python
pandas          2.2.0  Powerful data structures for data analysis, time series, and statistics
python-dateutil 2.8.2  Extensions to the standard Python datetime module
pytz            2024.1 World timezone definitions, modern and historical
six             1.16.0 Python 2 and 3 compatibility utilities
tzdata          2023.4 Provider of IANA time zone data
```